# Git Bad File Fatal Error

Tags: github, fatal-error

Git is saying that I need to pull before pushing to fast-forward but when I issue `git pull origin master` it returns this error:

```
fatal: failed to read object 12786e6d70d76ce47ecf69c30e4d0f994d1e2fc3: Invalid argument
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried doing `git cat-file -t 12786e6d70d76ce47ecf69c30e4d0f994d1e2fc3` but that returns `12786e6d70d76ce47ecf69c30e4d0f994d1e2fc3: bad file`

How do I see which file is the bad one and how can I fix it?

EDIT: To the war chest!

EDIT 2: can I just delete everything and begin again?

Comment: have you tried fetching?

Comment: Hm, perhaps you should fast-forward a remote. pull it into a new branch and then cherry-pick your commits onto it. With an issue like this, it could that you have really messed up! You should also check the permissions and disk space etc. Bare in mind that git is very flexible, however it doesn't meant that you shoudn't use with some methodology in mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted everything and pulled again. Couldn't get any work done so I had to do it :( Anyone who has any answers feel free to post.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same problem. Luckily, In the same repository in the other machine can be found by the `git cat-file <hash>` command. However, that file got packed.

So, I use

```
git cat-file commit [hash] > make_magic.txt
```

and copied that file to the corrupt repository machine, run

```
cat make_magic.txt | git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin
```

And after that, this problem got resolved.

This is really better way than fetch from the beginning. I have 30,000 revisions and take at least 14 days to restore the repository from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git clean && git pull`? You might want to backup your untracked files prior to issuing the commands.

Answer (score 0):

When I get `The remote end hung up unexpectedly` (under Windows) it usually means the network drive containing `origin` is not mounted.

Can you rule out `git` was just having connection problems?

Answer (score 0):

"git checkout -- ."  from the root project directory usually fixes such errors for me, if the connection / authentication is working .